# Does a transfer to a UK bank account affect the UK visa application process?

Tags: visas, uk

I live in the Netherlands. I am planning to visit UK in the year June. I would like to attend to a workshop there, this is the reason of my coming. I will stay in the UK for only a weekend (2 days). I am going to pay 1500 GBP for that workshop in this Monday, via bank transfer.

Here is my question. I guess I will submit my visa application as a Tourist (Standard visitors) visa. I am employed and I have a steady income. Might that money that I am going to pay be interpreted as suspicious by the consulate? Because I will be showing my bank statements.

Comment: What makes you think it would be seen as suspicious? It’s unexplained inward credits to an account that can cause suspicion of funds parking, not spending your own money to pay for a workshop. Having said that, you shouldn’t pay for anything (including travel, accommodation) before you know whether your visa is approved, unless you are certain you can get a refund if it’s not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope not at all. Anybody who goes for a tour to the U.K. is inevitably going to pay different accounts in the U.K. one way or another. Even hotel booking is one example.

Paying for a conference you are applying a visa for is certainly not a red flag at all.

Just note that they advise against making paid travel arrangements before securing your visa in case they refuse it. But if paying for the conference is a prerequisite for registration, it is not suspicious at all.